# getting a specific value from a formGroup to be called in another component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that contains a formGroup for authentication and I want to show the user login email on the navbar dynamically after the user logs in. I'm fairly new to Angular and I couldn't find any question regarding the formGroup

Here's the LoginComponent.html:

```
  <div class = "row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <h3>Sign In </h3>
     <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignin()" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
            <input
             type="email"
             id="email"
             name="email"
             class="form-control"
             formControlName="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input
             name="password"
             type="password"
             id="password"
             class="form-control"
             formControlName="password">
        </div>
        <br>
      <button
       class="btn btn-success"
       type="submit"
      [disabled]="!myForm.valid"
       >Sign In</button>
        <br>
        <hr>
      <label>ForgotPassword</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the LoginComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from     "@angular/forms";
import { AuthService } from "./auth/auth.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { User } from "../login/user.interface";
import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';

 @Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'login',
templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
styleUrls: [ 'login.component.css']
             })
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

@Input() myForm: FormGroup;
isAuthenticated = false;
private subscription: Subscription;
test1= false;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){
this.subscription = this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      authStatus => this.isAuthenticated = authStatus
    );
   }

onSignin() {
 this.authService.signinUser(this.myForm.value)
 this.router.navigate[('customer')];
  if (this.isAuthenticated){
alert("Login Successful ");
this.router.navigate(['customer']);
    }else{
    this.reset();
    }
  //routes the user after they have been authenticated
  }
 isAuth(){
  return this.isAuthenticated
       }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    });

  }

reset(){
this.myForm.reset();
   }
 ngOnDestroy(){

 this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

The interface:

```
export interface User {
email: string;
password: string;
   }
```

The navbar html:

```
     <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-item dropdown">
       <a href="#"
        class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
        id="nav-dropdown"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
        *ngIf="isAuth()">
        {{getEmail()}}
      </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item"
          (click)="onLogout()"
          style="cursor: pointer;"
          >Log Out</a>
       </ul>
     </li>
```

Method called from the navbar component:

```
 getEmail(user: User){
  //console.log(user.email.valueOf)
  this.test = "test"
  return this.test
 }
```

I attempted to use the interface, but I don't know if that is the best approach. Also, I more than likely have unnecessary imports in the Login Component, but its all experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way of doing this is set the local storage with the user information after authentication like this

`localStorage.setItem(email,'user_email');`   // or you can storage all the user information

```
getMail() : void
{
   this.email=localStorage.getItem("user_email'");
}
```

Comment: so where would I initialize this variable? in the Login Component or the Navbar Component? and does there have to be a reference to the form? or can I just initialize is like this?